# Why are polynomials chosen with coefficients in $GF(2^{8})$ in Section 4.3 of NIST FIPS 197 for implementing AES?

Tags: aes, rijndael

I was trying to understand  AES (Rijndael) from a very mathematical perspective. I'm quite new to abstract algebra and Galois Fields. I understood that we are considering a byte (8 bits) as a polynomial in $GF(2^{8}) $ where the coefficients are either $0$ or $1$ i.e. they are elements of `{0, 1}` and all operations are done modulo the Rijndael polynomial `0x11b` ($x^{8} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x + 1$). 
But Section 4.3 confused me a little when they are explaining that the coefficients themselves are considered as "bytes" i.e values from $0$ to $255$ . Can anyone please explain to me, why is this context switching possible, or why is it done?

> Four-term polynomials can be defined - with coefficients that are finite field elements - as: 
>   $a(x) = a_{3} x^{3} + a_{2} x^{2} + a_{1} x + a_{0}$ (4.5) 
>   which will be denoted as a word in the form $ [a_{0} , a_{1} , a_{2} , a_{3} ]$. Note that the polynomials in this 
>   section behave somewhat differently than the polynomials used in the definition of finite field 
>   elements, even though both types of polynomials use the same indeterminate, x. The coefficients 
>   in this section are themselves finite field elements, i.e., bytes, instead of bits; also, the 
>   multiplication of four-term polynomials uses a different reduction polynomial, defined below. 
>   The distinction should always be clear from the context.

Every help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: It is selected by Daemen and Rijmen [Rijndael ammended](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/documents/aes-development/rijndael-ammended.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The irreducible polynomial you showed above will create a polynomial field. (0x11b=283=100011011).

-now last nearest degree of 2 is ${2^8=256}$ hence all the operation of a field within the range of ${0,1..,255}$,

- It is a Byte operation because the range ${0,1,2,...,255}$ can be represented as a byte(8 bit) and the field operation are performed and reduced to modulo ${x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1}$
- Here, The statement ${\{0,1\}^8}$ means it can be a binary number of 8 bits.
- But in case of normal polynomial the coefficient can be from set N,Z,R,C. which is not the case in AES.